# Heroku Node/Postgres Deployment Error - code: h10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" status=503

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, heroku, deployment

I'm having trouble deploying my Node/Postgres App to Heroku. When I run my deploy script, the build completes, but after opening the database connection, an error is thrown for a missing module. My Procfile contains `web: node main.js` and my start script in the package.json states `"start": "node main"`.

Below I am attaching a copy of the `heroku logs` and the code in `main.js` which is in the root directory.

**Heroku Logs**

```
2021-01-09T23:23:17.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user ********@gmail.com
2021-01-09T23:23:34.407776+00:00 app[api]: Release v17 created by user ********@gmail.com
2021-01-09T23:23:34.407776+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 664cb125 by user ********@gmail.com
2021-01-09T23:23:34.721923+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2021-01-09T23:23:35.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2021-01-09T23:23:38.364250+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node main.js`
2021-01-09T23:23:41.218590+00:00 app[web.1]: Opening database connection to shoppies-nominator
2021-01-09T23:23:41.615336+00:00 app[web.1]: internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:818
2021-01-09T23:23:41.615350+00:00 app[web.1]: throw err;
2021-01-09T23:23:41.615350+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2021-01-09T23:23:41.615351+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-01-09T23:23:41.615351+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module 'volleyball'
2021-01-09T23:23:41.615352+00:00 app[web.1]: Require stack:
2021-01-09T23:23:41.615353+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/server/index.js
2021-01-09T23:23:41.615353+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/main.js
2021-01-09T23:23:41.615355+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:815:15)
2021-01-09T23:23:41.615356+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:667:27)
2021-01-09T23:23:41.615357+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19)
2021-01-09T23:23:41.615358+00:00 app[web.1]: at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
2021-01-09T23:23:41.615358+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/server/index.js:3:20)
2021-01-09T23:23:41.615359+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)
2021-01-09T23:23:41.615359+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
2021-01-09T23:23:41.615360+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
2021-01-09T23:23:41.615360+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
2021-01-09T23:23:41.615361+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19)
2021-01-09T23:23:41.615362+00:00 app[web.1]: at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
2021-01-09T23:23:41.615362+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/main.js:4:13)
2021-01-09T23:23:41.615362+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)
2021-01-09T23:23:41.615363+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
2021-01-09T23:23:41.615363+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
2021-01-09T23:23:41.615364+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
2021-01-09T23:23:41.615365+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:60:12)
2021-01-09T23:23:41.615366+00:00 app[web.1]: at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
2021-01-09T23:23:41.615366+00:00 app[web.1]: code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
2021-01-09T23:23:41.615367+00:00 app[web.1]: requireStack: [ '/app/server/index.js', '/app/main.js' ]
2021-01-09T23:23:41.615367+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2021-01-09T23:23:41.703611+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2021-01-09T23:23:41.752561+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-01-09T23:58:53.127855+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=shoppies-nominator.herokuapp.com request_id=010f5699-f805-4ce0-92a5-74225a0eb610 fwd="69.141.164.13" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

**main.js**

```
const {db} = require('./server/db')
const app = require('./server')
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5409

db.sync()
  .then(() => {
    console.log('db synced')
    app.listen(PORT, (e) => {
      if (e) throw (e)
      console.log(`Listening on port ${PORT}`)
    })
})
```

Any ideas?

Comment: As the log says you're missing the npm module volleyball, can you run the service locally. Maybe its in your node_modules folder but not in your package.json in server, you are probably doing something like app.use(volleyall)

Comment: Yes, I can run the app locally, and I have volleyball in my `package.json`. As for where it's used, I `require` it into a `server/index.js` file, then call it inside an `app.use()`

Comment: what happens if you clear node modules folder and package-lock.json and do npm install again and then npm run start?

Comment: I get the same error log whether I delete my `node_modules` and reinstall `npm` or delete the Heroku app and create a new one.